# Could a chipped tiling flange on acrylic tub cause problems in the future?

Tags: bathtub, damage

I just had my plumber install an acrylic alcove tub with double tiling flange and noticed afterwards that he must have chipped the corner of the tiling flange acrylic during the process. From what I can see:

- The fiberglass underneath looks to be intact and undamaged
- The chip is small enough that I'm sure it'll be covered by the tile wall surround being installed later
- There does not seem to be any cracks radiating out from the chip right now

Should I be concerned about this chip causing problems (e.g. cracks to spread in the acrylic) down the road, or is that risk unlikely? If I should be concerned, would repairing the acrylic do the trick or should I have a new tub installed?

[image: Picture of the chip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be fine. There's nothing there that'll rot or degrade over time.

(I know this is a short answer, but that's really all there is to say on the subject.)

Comment: Indeed. Consider that the screw is probably putting more stress on the tub than the chipped area will ever see. I'm frankly a bit dubious about using a flathead deck screw on a tub, evidently without countersinking...that's some serious stress.

Comment: Canadians, eh? Agree that a pan head would be a much better choice.

Comment: Also, you don't screw through the flange, you go on top. That's worse than the chip.... which is meh, +1

Comment: Thanks all for putting my mind at ease. Interestingly enough the instructions for this tub instruct to screw through the flange, and their diagram even includes using a flathead screw. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ good to know for next time.